# ::Before element not properly floating on a floating element

Tags: html, css, css-float, pseudo-element

Having a basic html and css as following,

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}
.float {
  float: left
}
h1 {
  font-size: 2em
}
h2 {
  font-size: 1em
}
hgroup::before {
  float: left;
  font-size: 3em;
  padding: 0 .1em;
  content: ':)'
}
```

```html
<hgroup>
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <h2>World</h2>
</hgroup>
<hr />
<hgroup class="float">
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <h2>World</h2>
</hgroup>
```

I wish to have ::before to float to the left of its own element.

It works well until the element itself floats as well. When that happens, ::before does not float anymore.

Is there a way to have it to work without adding a container element?

Comment: By floating the element itself, it shrinks to fit its contents, hence there would be no room for other line-boxes to wrap the inner floated child. As a proof you can give the element a width, e.g. 50% or something.

Comment: It IS floating...
You can't see it because:
1. For the first hgroup it is it's normal position too
2. The second hgroup floating left by itslef

Too see it change float's value to right...

Answer (score 0):

add this to you `.float` class    `width: 100%;`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}
.float {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 2em
}
h2 {
  font-size: 1em
}
hgroup::before {
  float: left;
  font-size: 3em;
  padding: 0 .1em;
  content: ':)'
}
```

```html
<hgroup>
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <h2>World</h2>
</hgroup>
<hr />
<hgroup class="float">
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <h2>World</h2>
</hgroup>
```

Comment: Giving a floating element a width of 100% kind of negates the floating property, doesn't it? Might as well remove the float then.

Comment: If that is the case can you give a min-width so that your contents can fit in a single row.